# Make image fit circle avatar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display a users profile picture inside a circle avatar widget but only a small portion of it is displayed.

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 70,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("Images/headshot_1.jpg"),
)
```

[Image I am trying to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RUPF.jpg)

Screenshot on emulator:

[image]

Update: I got it to work by wrapping the circle avatar in a row widget.

Comment: have you tried fit :BoxFit.contain ?

Answer (score 9):

Wrap **CircleAvatar** widget with **Center** widget
Example:

```
Center(child:CircleAvatar())
```

Comment: That one is cool

Comment: This is working like margic but i don't know why it is working. Please kindly explain if possible

Comment: working like magic indeed. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using `foregroundImage`. As the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar/foregroundImage.html) states, this property works well in your use case: a profile picture.

Here's an example with the image you displayed in your question:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            foregroundImage: AssetImage(
              'myimage.png',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT.** Added the obtained UI.
Here's what I obtain:
[image: Avatarized image]

If your problem persists, the problem lies somewhere else in your context / widget tree.

Comment: I still get the same effect using foregroundImage.

Comment: Have you tried with the "child" property, instead?

Comment: I have but it didn't work, I got it to work by wrapping the circle avatar with a row widget.

Comment: Could you update your real image you want to "avatarize" in your original question, so that I can experiment with it? It works on my side with some dummy image

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with what I obtain with exactly that code. Your issue probably depends on the rest of your widget tree / context.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`child`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html#child) property, which takes another widget.

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 70,
  child: Image.asset(
    "Images/headshot_1.jpg",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    height: 140,
    width: 140,
  ),
);
```

I tried running your code and it came out to be circle. I used 512px from https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/avatar_168724

You should check the avatar image you are using.

Comment: Thanks but it ultimately gave me a square image.

Comment: can you paste the image you are drawing inside CircleAvatar.

Answer (score -1):

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 70,
  child: Image.asset('assets/1.png',
fit :BoxFit.cover,
),
)
```

Comment: the `CircleAvatar` does not have a `fit` parameter

Comment: use backgroundImage image instead of using child parameter